# Sanitize Attribute Name

Tags: php, regex, html, encoding

Based on the [html syntax docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) and trial and error in the [validator](http://html5.validator.nu/) I believe that the allowed characters in HTML attribute names are:

- alphanumerics
- hyphens
- underscores
- periods

For example these **validate**:

```
<p data-éxample>
<p data-1.5>
```

I want to write a function for sanitizing attribute names:

```
<?php 
function sanitize_attr_name ( $name ) {
    return is_string($name) ? preg_replace( '/[^\w\-\.]/', '', $name ) : '';
}
```

That works except for the special alpha characters:

```
sanitize_attr_name( 'data-éxample' ); // 'data-xample'
```

Now it may seem crazy for someone to use characters like that but it [does in fact work](http://jsfiddle.net/VfUU8/2/) albeit the css doesn't seem to validate [escaped or not](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

How do you pull that off in PHP? How could the sanitizer be written to allow for the special alpha characters? Is that possible via regexp? And why is `ctype_graph('é')` false?

Comment: Your regex is correct and should work. Can you try being more specific and use the following regex `[^A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]`

Comment: @Pogo Yup that's the same regex. It wipes out the special alpha chars like `é`. I'm curious to know if it's possible to whitelist/target the special alpha chars via regex or otherwise.

Comment: @ryanve try replacing `\w` with `\p{L}`. [PHP'S PCRE Unicode documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP's regex engine PCRE supports [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) with `\p{property}`. One of these properties is `L` which is the property of **any** letter. So you could just replace `\w` by `\p{L}0-9_`:

```
'/[^\p{L}0-9_.-]/'
```

There is also no need to escape periods in character classes, and hyphens can be put at the end to avoid escaping.

Comment: Nice—that's what I'm talkin' bout =] Thanks. The preg_replace works with that. The special alpha chars show up as as question mark diamonds but I think that must have to do with the PHP settings b/c in a local .html file the chars show up.